# How to compare two different row of a table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following colomn

**ID TAG VALUE**

The value in the table is something like this

```
1   ac.id      12345
1   ac.title   xyz 
2   ac.id      12345
2.  ac.title   Yo its the title
```

In this I want to compare the value of two different id that has same tag and if the value is different then update the id that is lesser

for example

value of ac.title is different in for id 2 and 1 so i will update the value of 1 with the 2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is still to use a join, but its something like this:

```
update test t1 
  left join test t2
    on t1.id < t2.id
      and t1.name = t2.name
  set t1.value = t2.value
  where t2.id is not null;
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc400/1)

You may need to run it more than once if you have several rows with the same tag but different ids.  If thats a significant problem, just comment and i'll come up with a different query - this is just the quick and easy solution.

**edit**

And here's the slightly more complicated but more effective solution. This will update ALL the tags with a lower ID to the value of the tag with the MAX ID.

```
update test t1
  inner join
  (
    select q1.*, t2.value from
    (
      select max(id) id, name
        from test
        group by name
    ) q1
    inner join test t2
      on q1.id = t2.id
        and q1.name = t2.name
  ) m
  on t1.name = m.name
    and t1.id < m.id
  set t1.value = m.value
```

[alternate fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15c43/1)

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40f442/1

```
UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM table1) t
  ON t.tag=table1.tag 
  AND t.val != table1.val
  AND t.id > table1.id
SET table1.val = t.val
```

Comment: you know you can just inner join the table again and alias it right? no need to `select * from table1` in a subquery there at all?